# Botão para copiar o html da página

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Preciso disponibilizar um botão onde os usuários irão apenas clicar e copiar todo o código que foi utilizado para desenvolver aquela página.

Eu vi muitas perguntas parecidas, mas nenhuma conseguiu resolver o meu problema. Seria basicamente assim, imaginem que o código exemplo abaixo corresponde a página que eu preciso copiar:

```
  <div class="conteudo-total">       
       <div>
           <h1>Titulo</h1>
           <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aperiam laboriosam inventore blanditiis repellendus corrupti, ea, maxime magnam odio, vero consequatur, dolores hic. Accusantium voluptatem nulla velit, deserunt sequi eveniet debitis.</p>
       </div>       
 </div>   
 <div class="copiar">Copiar Código</div>
```

Quando clicar em `Copiar Código` preciso copiar todo conteúdo `html`, ou seja, todo o conteúdo do arquivo. Eu sei que seria muito mais simples ir no arquivo e copiar o código diretamente de lá, mas é uma requisito indispensável que seja através de um botão...

Comment: Pode utilizar `JQuery`?

Comment: Sim sim, eu inclusive tentei algumas formas em jQuery, mas não consegui.

Comment: ta, mas eae? ele vai colar aonde isso?

Comment: se for só o html css e js da página tu pode usar var code = document.body.innerHTML;

Comment: Julio Henrique, será colado em outros projetos, por ser uma página modelo

Comment: Boa, Anderson, não tinha pensado nisso. Mas você saberia como copiar o conteúdo dessa variável code, como se fosse um ctrl+c?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fiz uma função para copiar o `HTML` da página atual através do botão, porém dependendo do navegador, é gerado alguns 'lixos' na compilação, principalmente no `opera`, no `chrome` e no `mozilla` é tranquilo, e localmente é perfeito, caso eu descubra como retirar esse tipo de imperfeição edito a resposta, segue a função...

```js
function copiarHTML() {
        let copyText = document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0];
        let input = document.createElement("input");
        input.id = "inp";
        input.value = copyText.outerHTML;
        copyText.appendChild(input);
        
        let copy = document.getElementById('inp');
        copy.select();
        document.execCommand("Copy");
        alert("O texto copiado foi: " + copy.value);
        
        copyText.removeChild(input);

        let textArea = document.createElement('textarea');
        textArea.cols = "80";
        textArea.rows = "40";
        textArea.placeholder = "Pressione Ctrl+v aqui";

        copyText.appendChild(textArea);
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Copiar HTML</title>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="copiarHTML()">
        Copiar HTML
    </button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Era isso mesmo que eu precisava, muito obrigado!

Comment: e se você detectar se o navegador é o opera?

Answer (score 1):

**Com javascript puro**

```js
function copiarHtml() {
    var x = document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0];
    var z = x.outerHTML;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = z;
    document.getElementById("demo").select();
    document.execCommand('copy');
}
```

```css
    //para fora da viewport
    #demo{
      position :absolute;
      top: -1000px;
      left: -1000px;
    }
```

```html
<button onclick="copiarHtml()">Copiar HTML</button>

<textarea id="demo"></textarea>
<br>
<textarea placeholder="cole aqui"></textarea>
```

**Com Jquery**

```js
$('button').click(function(){
  var txt = document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0];

  $('textarea.hide').text( txt.outerHTML) ;
  $("textarea.hide").select();
  document.execCommand('copy');
});
```

```css
//para fora da viewport
textarea.hide{
  position :absolute;
  top: -1000px;
  left: -1000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button>Copie meu html</button>
<br />
<textarea class="hide"></textarea>

<textarea placeholder="cole aqui"></textarea>
```

**Com PHP**

Biblioteca

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

CSS

```
<style type="text/css">
//para fora da viewport
.hide {
    position: absolute;
    top: -1000px;
    left: -1000px
}
</style>
```

SCRIPT

```
<script language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("textarea").select();
        document.execCommand('copy');
    });
});
</script>
```

PHP + HTML

```
<?php
    // Lê todo o conteúdo de um arquivo
    $html = file_get_contents("Nome_do_arquivo_para_ler");

    $html = htmlentities($html);

    echo "<textarea class='hide'>". $html ."</textarea>";

?>

<button>Copie meu html</button>
```

> Já que Copiar texto de elementos ocultos não funciona (limitação de segurança do navegador), todos os exemplos acima usam a técnica `“off -left”` (descrito no ScreenreaderVisibility no
>   css-discuss Wiki), que envolve o posicionamento absoluto do elemento escondido
>   para fora da viewport.

**Porém é possível copiar texto de elementos ocultos utilizando a técnica a seguir:**

Comentários no próprio código

```js
var copyBtn   = $("#copy-btn"),
textarea     = $("#copy-me");
    //conteúdo do arquivo
    var x = document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0];
    var z = x.outerHTML;
    document.getElementById("copy-me").innerHTML = z;

function copyToClipboard() {
  var success   = true,
      range     = document.createRange(),
      selection;

  // IE.
  if (window.clipboardData) {
    window.clipboardData.setData("Text", textarea.val());        
  } else {
    // Crie um elemento temporário fora da tela.
    var tmpElem = $('<div>');
    tmpElem.css({
      position: "absolute",
      left:     "-1000px",
      top:      "-1000px",
    });
    // Adicione o valor de entrada ao elemento temporário
    tmpElem.text(textarea.val());
    $("body").append(tmpElem);
    //Selecione o elemento temporario.
    range.selectNodeContents(tmpElem.get(0));
    selection = window.getSelection ();
    selection.removeAllRanges ();
    selection.addRange (range);
    // Permite copiar.
    try { 
      success = document.execCommand ("copy", false, null);
    }
    catch (e) {
      copyToClipboardFF(textarea.val());
    }
    if (success) {
      alert ("O código fonte desta página está na área de transferência, cole-o!");
      // remove o elemento temporario.
      tmpElem.remove();
    }
  }
}

copyBtn.on('click', copyToClipboard);
```

```css
#copy-me {
    display:none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea name="" id="copy-me"/></textarea>
<button id="copy-btn">Copiar HTML</button><br/><br/>
<textarea placeholder="cole aqui"></textarea>
```

[Fonte - do brother DavidDomain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31593297/using-execcommand-javascript-to-copy-hidden-text-to-clipboard/31596687#31596687)